# Rewriting all unit vectors of a 2-dimensional complex vector space.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

The fact below is used in a [post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4694) regarding the Bloch sphere.

---

Let $V$ be a two dimensional complex vector space. The collection of all unit vectors of $V$ can be written as
$$\left\{e^{i\gamma}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\vec{v} + e^{i\phi}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\vec{w}\right) : \gamma, \theta, \phi\in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2$ the coordinates of your unit vector in the orthonormal basis $(v,w).$ Since $|x|^2+|y|^2=1,$ there exists a real number $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ such that $|x|=\cos\frac\theta2$ and $|y|=\sin\frac\theta2.$

Then, $x=|x|e^{i\gamma}$ for some $\gamma\in[0,2\pi)$ and next, $ye^{-i\gamma}=|y|e^{i\phi}$ for some $\phi\in[0,2\pi).$

This way, your unit vector is written like you wrote.

Conversely, a vector written like that is obviously of norm $1.$